# How to increase partition size in ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-14.04, gparted, diskpart

I have a ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine on Azure, with a OS disk of size 30 GB.

When I increased the size of OS disk to 50 GB, the size of the partition(/dev/sda1) was not increased to 50 GB and it remained 30 GB.

After doing RDP to the machine I found the additional 20GB is present as free space.

Question 1- Could anyone please tell me why this happened?

I installed GParted on my system, but I am unable to unmount the partition(/dev/sda1).

Question 2- Could anyone tell me how to unmount the partition and increase the size of the partition using GParted or cmd?

Comment: You don't need to unmount - see [How can I expand ext4 partition size on debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67107)

Comment: See also, this _Related_ page: https://superuser.com/questions/394085/how-extend-linux-partition-with-gparted-cd-live?rq=1